# Cloud Service Provider For HPC Testing

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm looking to do some benchmarking for a project I've been working on in C++/Python.

I've so far tried numerous cloud vm's on AWS and Google. The best performance I've gotten on the Cloud was with Google's t2d instance (w/ Ubuntu), running with 60 logical cores and a 200GB SSD. Some of my tests spawn up to 32 parallel processes and even with that I'm getting far better performance on my M2 Mac at home (8 cores). For example, the difference of 126Gbps vs 26Gbps for one of my tests. I understand that these cloud data service providers like to keep costs low and can limit the utilization of hardware/clock speed, but I need to find an alternative to provide similar performance of the M2, with more cores. Any idea where I can get some better performance on the cloud?

Comment: You might be interested in bare metal machines.

Comment: @DimaChubarov tried this on AWS, still not comparable

Comment: Probably more details needed to understand what's going on. What is your benchmark? Is it cpu-bound or io-bound?

Comment: +1 to @DimaChubarov comment. Just CPU and cores wont  give best performance. You would need to use the correct  Storage with provisioned IOPS and also if there is network IO then appropriate instance type needs to be selected.